# How to fix coding keys error with JSON conversion

Tags: json, swiftui

I have an API call that has a ViewModel that takes in an API and transfers the data into an Array. I keep on getting an error with the conversion to JSON.

ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var courses: [Course] = []
    
    func fetch() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.spaceflightnewsapi.net/v3/articles") else {
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self]data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            // Convert to JSON
            do {
                let courses = try JSONDecoder().decode([Course].self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.courses = courses
                }
            } catch {
                print(error) //---Error Here---
                print("Error with converting to JSON")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Course is defined as:

```
struct Course: Hashable, Codable {
    let name: String
    let image: String
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let newsSite: String
    let summary: String
    let publishedAt: String
    let updatedAt: String
    let featured: Bool
    let launches: String
    let events: String
}
```

I then get the error:

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil) ("name").", underlyingError: nil))

Have I forgot to do something inside of the `Course` struct?

Comment: There is no tag named name in the data you can get with your url. Set name as optional or remove it

Comment: Could you please show me where the tag is? I don't see a tag named `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`...to fix coding keys error with JSON conversion`, try this exapme code,
that is, your models structs need to match the json data.

There is no `name`, and no `image` in the json data, also  `launches` and `events` are not String.

```
struct Course: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let url: String // <-- here
    let imageUrl: String // <-- here
    let newsSite, summary, publishedAt, updatedAt: String
    let featured: Bool
    let launches: [Launch]?  // <-- here
    let events: [Event]? // <-- here
}

struct Event: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    let id: Int
    let provider: String
}

struct Launch: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    let id, provider: String
}
```

Note, you will need to consult the docs to determine which properties are optional. In that case add `?` to it.

Comment: Yup, this worked, I guess that I didn't take a look at the docs properly and I then found out that the launches, events, and URLs were all optional. Thank you!